# Unable to serve Jekyll website locally on macOS High Sierra with Ruby 3.2.2: SASS error

Tags: ruby, sass, jekyll, macos-high-sierra

I need help please. I’m trying to run `bundle exec jekyll serve` on a relatively old macOS system (High Sierra, v10.13.6) with Ruby v3.2.2 and the latest Jekyll, but I encounter the following error:

```
/Users/mabalenk/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/sass-embedded-1.68.0-x86_64-darwin/lib/sass/embedded/connection.rb:28: warning: VM initialization failed: Current Mac OS X version 10.13 is lower than minimum supported version 10.14
  Conversion error: Jekyll::Converters::Scss encountered an error while converting 'assets/main.scss':
                    end of file reached
bundler: failed to load command: jekyll (/Users/mabalenk/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/bin/jekyll)
/Users/mabalenk/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/sass-embedded-1.68.0-x86_64-darwin/lib/sass/embedded/varint.rb:20:in `readbyte': end of file reached (EOFError)
    from /Users/mabalenk/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/sass-embedded-1.68.0-x86_64-darwin/lib/sass/embedded/varint.rb:20:in `block in read'
    from /Users/mabalenk/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/sass-embedded-1.68.0-x86_64-darwin/lib/sass/embedded/varint.rb:19:in `loop'
    from /Users/mabalenk/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/sass-embedded-1.68.0-x86_64-darwin/lib/sass/embedded/varint.rb:19:in `read'
    from /Users/mabalenk/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/sass-embedded-1.68.0-x86_64-darwin/lib/sass/embedded/connection.rb:62:in `block in read'
    from /Users/mabalenk/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/sass-embedded-1.68.0-x86_64-darwin/lib/sass/embedded/connection.rb:61:in `synchronize'
    from /Users/mabalenk/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/sass-embedded-1.68.0-x86_64-darwin/lib/sass/embedded/connection.rb:61:in `read'
    from /Users/mabalenk/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/sass-embedded-1.68.0-x86_64-darwin/lib/sass/embedded/dispatcher.rb:77:in `receive_proto'
    from /Users/mabalenk/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/sass-embedded-1.68.0-x86_64-darwin/lib/sass/embedded/dispatcher.rb:19:in `block (2 levels) in initialize'
    from /Users/mabalenk/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/sass-embedded-1.68.0-x86_64-darwin/lib/sass/embedded/dispatcher.rb:18:in `loop'
    from /Users/mabalenk/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/sass-embedded-1.68.0-x86_64-darwin/lib/sass/embedded/dispatcher.rb:18:in `block in initialize'
```

**Update**

I noticed the following message while installing Jekyll:

```
Ruby Sass has reached end-of-life and should no longer be used.

* If you use Sass as a command-line tool, we recommend using Dart Sass, the new
  primary implementation: https://sass-lang.com/install

* If you use Sass as a plug-in for a Ruby web framework, we recommend using the
  sassc gem: https://github.com/sass/sassc-ruby#readme

* For more details, please refer to the Sass blog:
  https://sass-lang.com/blog/posts/7828841
```

Maybe I need to use the new `sassc` gem?

Comment: _Current Mac OS X version 10.13 is lower than minimum supported version 10.14_ Did you consider updating MacOS or downgrading sass-embedded to a version that was released when MacOS 10.13 was up-to-date?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can no longer update macOS. It is locked to this version by Apple. This is the highest I can install. Yes, I will try to downgrade sass-embedded gem.